# Jquery only works once playing video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following code. My objective is to when I press the img in the first div, it transforms in a iframe with a video inside. And when I click the close (glyphicon) it gets back to the original state.
It is working, **the problem is that it only works once.**

If its necessary I can make a version to run in the snippet.

Also, if you know a better way to do this, please tell me. :)

Thanks

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="squarediv"><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/any/1" data-img="https://placeimg.com/400/400/any/1" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/72a27aLQ5B8">
   </div>

   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

**scripts.js**

```
$('img').click(function () {
    video = '<iframe class="videop" src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '?modestbranding=1;autoplay=1;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
    $(".squarediv").addClass("squarediv-active");
});

$('.close').click(function () {
    img = '<img src="' + $('.squarediv img').attr('data-img') + '" data-img="' + $('.squarediv img').attr('data-img') + '" data-video="' + $('.squarediv img').attr('data-video') + '" ></img>';
    $('.videop').replaceWith(img);
    $(".squarediv").removeClass("squarediv-active");
    $(".close").addClass("close-active");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you use `replaceWith()`. This means that the original elements, along with the event handlers attached to them, are removed.

To fix the issue, use a delegated event handler, like this:

```
$('div.col-md-6').on('click', 'img', function () {
  // your code...
}).on('click', '.close', function() {
  // your code...
});
```

Note that the `div.col-md-6` primary selector can be changed to any common parent element which is in the DOM on load, I only used that as it was the only thing available in the sample HTML you provided in the question.

Comment: **Perfect!I** thought the replaceWith() would work because i was passing the handlers. Thanks very much for this :)